# What kind of cohomology is meant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

What kind of cohomology is meant in Deligne's work about mixed hodge structure on cohomology groups of an complex algebraic variety? I think it refers to the singular cohomology with coefficients in C. But what topology do I have to put on the variety? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It means the singular cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ in the analytic topology. Are you familiar with ordinary Hodge structures? It means the same thing there.